# How to make application that stores orders and prints receipts?

Tags: java, frameworks, libraries

I want to create an offline computer application for my dad.

My dad is a gardener and sells many different things.  If a person buys for example 2 cucumbers and 4 tomatoes we want to store it as order number 1. Then another person buys 3 cucumbers and 3 salads and we want to store that as order 2. So the program should be able to store those things and then print it out on paper.
The program should also be able to say how many tomatoes was sold in each month.

I have learned some of the basics of Java for the past 2 weeks, but I haven't learned about libraries and frameworks.
What would be the easiest way to make the application?  Should I use some library or framework?

Comment: Because you look like beginner I really recomend you to not use `Java` because there are many easier languages like `PHP` or `python` nowadays that have good examples online.

Comment: Maybe even excel sheet could work well for that?

Comment: Better still, try looking for an existing product that will do the job for your Dad.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others above you should definitly follow thier advice, but if you intend to build the application yourself i would reckon you to read some basics of core java thoroughly like OOP'S concept's,multithreading,Exception handling,Collections(IMPORTANT), and for designing GUI java Swing could be a good option for new beginner and basically you should also learn MySql database as it is easy to program with java, and as per your requirements you need to keep to track of items available and sold which could be easily accomplished with MySQL, hence you need to also brush up with JDBC to communicate with MySQL from java programs. Before you go on with building your application i would reckon you to do much coding if possible while learning these concept's.All of this might take time. Hope this helps you for your project. BEST OF LUCK.